# Missing comment notifications?

Tags: bug, comments, notifications

Has anyone else been having missing notifications? I posted an answer on a Meta thread and had two users comment on it, but I never received any notification for the comments. Has anyone else been experiencing this? Is this a bug, or do notifications on Meta work differently?

Another odd thing happened as well. I responded in a comment when only one comment was posted. When I went back and checked later, there was a second comment that appeared between mine and the first, with a posting time about an hour earlier than mine. I could chalk this up to being oblivious and forgetting or missing the second comment, but combined with the missing notifications it made me suspicious there might be something else going on.

Comment: Meta isn't supposed to work differently.  Can you link to the question with the odd sequencing?  Also, did you get a notification for this comment?

Comment: @MonicaCellio I did get this notification. The post I was missing notifications from is [this one](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6083/16983).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You clarified in a comment that you're talking about [this post](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6083/16983).  I *think* (based on seeing those comments earlier) that Mister Positive deleted and then undeleted his comment -- not sure and the mod tools don't show that history, but it's possible that the deletion revoked the notification and the undeletion didn't restore it.

When somebody comments on your post you get a notification, but if the comment is deleted the notification disappears.  Since undeleting comments is super-rare, I'll bet the code doesn't look for that and reinstate the inbox notification.

Comment: Very interesting, and makes a lot of sense! Since it seems to be a super-rare edge case, I'm not too worried about getting it fixed. Thanks!